# Format date using SLDS style class

Tags: datetime, lightning-design-system, outputtext

I don't want my date and time to show up GMT on a custom visualforce page. I have a date/time field I'm pulling in from the opportunity here is my VFP code:

```
    <div class="slds-truncate slds-text-body_small">
    <p>Pricing Due {!ThisOpportunity.Pricing_Due_Date_Time__c} </p></div>
```

It displays like this though

> Pricing Due Thu May 25 16:00:00 GMT 2017

Comment: Use outputfield or java messaging format. Same as when not using slds

Comment: How do you like to see the format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `apex:outputText` to show the formatted date:

```
<div class="slds-truncate slds-text-body_small">
    <p>Pricing Due 
        <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
            <apex:param value="{!ThisOpportunity.Pricing_Due_Date_Time__c}" /> 
        </apex:outputText>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: As an you can always use APEX:OUTPUTFIELD and the date time value will display in the user's time zone settings already: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000097dVIAQ